# Angles of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

In a parallelogram $ABCD$, if angle $A = (3x+20)°$, angle $B = (y+15)°$, angle $C = (x+40)°$, then what are the values of $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see fig.1

angle of A= angle of C
$$3x+20=x+40$$
$$x=10$$
the angle of B plus angle of C=180

$$x+40^{\circ}+y+15^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$$
$$y=115$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$3x+20^{\circ}+y+15^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$$ and $$x+40^{\circ}+y+15^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$$

Comment: can you please solve it and share the whole steps with me?